# Crontab is not working in plesk after changing the path too

Tags: php, cron, plesk, cron-task

Hi i have tried to run the php file in the plesk by using cronjob by the following commands.But everything is showing the errors. Not executing the php script.

i.e.,

```
php -q /path to the file
```

shows php command not found.so i have tried to find the path for php by using

```
which php
```

it displays the path /usr/bin/php. after that i have tried with

```
/usr/bin/php -q /path to the file
```

it shows  `/usr/bin/php` no such file or directory

The same way i tried for

```
/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/php -q /path to the file

/usr/bin/curl /url of the file

/usr/bin/wget /url of the file
```

every thing is showing the error and not executing the script. what is wrong with this. Can any one suggest me. thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll tell you what worked for us.
First of all, we checked that cURL is installed. It wasn't so we installed it.
Then we followed the following steps:

```
http://shaun.net/2011/09/solving-plesk-10-3-1-cron-issues/
```

> To fix the problem and restore behaviour to how it worked in previous
>   versions of Plesk, all you need to do is run the following command:
>   /usr/local/psa/bin/server_pref -u -crontab-secure-shell "/bin/sh"

But you have to find the correct route of your file "server_pref". 
Following these steps, we are able to use the cron with curl -q http://youradress.com/cron.php

Hope it helps, best regards